# Looking up a column value based on two column values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I need to get the value from a column based on two specific column values.

Example Dataframe:

```
   Charge Code  Billing Number   Date 
0   1250-001      500220        1/2/20
1   1230-002      300220        2/6/20
2   1250-001      500320        3/8/20
3   1225-001      250120        4/9/20
4   1225-002      250120        5/16/20
5   1136-010      361219        12/9/19
```

I want to get the date for the row that has the charge code 1250-001 and Billing Number 500320 (which would be 3/8/20)

I am attempting to use the following line:

```
the_date = df_hold.loc[df_hold['Charge Code'] == '1250' & df_hold['Billing Number'] == 500320].index.values
```

and am receiving the following error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [1250-001] is not in the [index]'
```

After using: 
    the_date = df_hold.loc[(df_hold['Charge Code'] == '1250-001') & 
                       (df_hold['Billing Number'] == 500320), 'Date']

I got the following:

```
configure_logger, configure_logger.setup_logger
3    3/8/2020
Name: Invoice Date, dtype: object
```

is there a way to get the date by itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis:

```
the_date = df_hold.loc[(df_hold['Charge Code'] == '1250-001') & 
                       (df_hold['Billing Number'] == 500320), 'Date']
```

update:

```
the_date = df_hold.loc[(df_hold['Charge Code'] == '1250-001') & 
                       (df_hold['Billing Number'] == 500320), 'Date'].to_numpy()
```

or

```
the_date = df_hold.loc[(df_hold['Charge Code'] == '1250-001') & 
                       (df_hold['Billing Number'] == 500320), 'Date'].to_numpy()[0]
```

Comment: I have added more to the question based on the output I received from this solution.